# Identifying a transformer I pulled out of an Ashly FTX 2001 Series amplifier

Tags: transformer

I have a transformer that I pulled out of an Ashly FTX-2001 250WCHAN amplifier and was hoping someone could possibly point me in the right direction as to finding schematics on it or would be able to give me some information about it. It would be greatly appreciated.

Markings on the transformer:

- TABTRONICS 51P4001E
- 5A303
- Sn 04060

Comment: You could start by looking at how the transformer was originally connected in the circuit; i.e. where does the mains go in to find primary terminals and where do the amplifier gets the supply to find the secondary output terminals that power the amp.

Comment: [Ashly publishes a manual.](https://ashly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ftx1001-1501-2001-amplifiers-r07.pdf) Page 17 has [this bock diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn5FG.png) followed by a nice schematic on page 18 that helps clarify many details. Why didn't you find this and document it here to help out? It was the very first item on a google search using ***only*** the name Ashly and FTX-2001, for me. And it should be, I think, helpful for anyone trying to help you. You should add it to your question if that diagram appear to document what you have in hand.

Answer (score 2):

Transformers in consumer products are all custom. The part number is an internal part number and means nothing to the rest of us. The information about that transformer is intellectual property of Ashly and is not available externally. TABTRONICS built is specifically for Ashly.

You will need to reverse engineer that transformer, using a meter and noting how it was connected inside that product.

Comment: Thanks man much appreciated learn something new everyday